# If every non-trivial subsequence of some sequence converges to a same limit, does the sequence itself converges to that limit?

Tags: analysis

While studying Analysis, I've learned that "If a sequence converges to limit L, every subsequence converges to L as well." I'm just wondering if the converse can be true, but I can't prove it neither find a counterexample. If anyone could help, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: What do you mean my non-trivial subsequence?

Comment: @ArpanSadhukhan I meant subsequences that aren't identical to the original sequence.

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the first term of the sequence, the remaining terms forms a subsequence of the original sequence and it converges to some limit $L$( by your claim), so the original sequence also converges to $L$.